# How to tell mac executable to pick up jar from current directory

Tags: java, macos, executable, executable-jar

I have **Mac** executable that has below lines

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar <absolute_path>/jar_file.jar
```

If we don't mention absolute path above, As I know it will search in mac user dir and will give error as "unable to access jar", So to avoid this we give absolute path, but absolute path will not help when you move the executable to another machine.

***So how to make executable work at any place without modifying above path every time we move***

Answer (score 0):

You can steal the appropriate code from the `mvn` script:

```sh
## resolve links - $0 may be a link to Maven's home                             
PRG="$0"                                                                        
                                                                                
# need this for relative symlinks                                               
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do                                                        
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`                                                            
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`                                            
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then                                     
    PRG="$link"                                                                 
  else                                                                          
    PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"                                                
  fi                                                                            
done                                                                            
                                                                                
saveddir=`pwd`
```

`PRG` will equal "<absolute_path>/executable.bash"; the JAR will be at

```
`dirname $PRG`/jar_file.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unix systems, the tilde (~) character is a shortcut for user's home directory.
The ~ character can be used to replace the absolute path to user's home directory.

**Working Example using ~ :**

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar ~/jar_file.jar
```

The user home can have different absolute paths on different systems,
but ~ in the above script will resolve to the the correct user home directory path.

Comment: Will this work if I place my executable at any folder? Because you mentioned~ represent user home directory.. Means executable should be at users/<username>/ ?